# Error Message Dart 2.5 The for, if, and spread elements weren't supported until version 2.2.2

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

Use of the spread (...) element produces the following error:

"The for, if, and spread elements weren't supported until version 2.2.2, but this code is required to be able to run on earlier versions.
Try updating the SDK constraints."

Changing pubspec.yaml to:

```
 environment:
    sdk: ">=2.x <3.0.0"
```

for values of x from 2.2 up to 5.0 doesn't remove the error. Autofix just sets it to ">=2.2.2 <3.0.0".

The code runs fine, it's just an annoyance as there is one instance of the error for each file it's used in - which leads to the Problem window being full of pointless messages. Is there the possibility that something is requiring a lower version of the sdk, and if so what/where might it be?

---

Flutter 1.9.1+hotfix.6 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git

Framework • revision 68587a0916 (6 weeks ago) • 2019-09-13 19:46:58 -0700

Engine • revision b863200c37

Tools • Dart 2.5.0

Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.295], locale en-GB)

Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.1)

Android Studio (version 3.4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting sdk: ">=2.5.0 <3.0.0" **and** restarting VSC solves the problem (along with now being able to find packages it had installed but insisted didn't exist). I have been in this game more than long enough that I should know that turning if off and on again solves 99.9% of problems #facepalm

Answer (score 2):

In **pubspec.yaml** you can update your **environment sdk** to get rid of those warnings:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.3.0 <3.0.0"
```

Enjoy the code :)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting it this way:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.5.0 <3.0.0"
```

I have this on my project and works fine!

Comment: already tried it "for values of x from 2.2 up to 5.0", tried it again, no dice :-/